# My onClick button will not execute the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

This is my `javascipt` function: I am trying to swap an image, en be able to swap it back again with a `button`. But for some reason, it won't execute the script.

**Javascript**

```
function changeImage() {

    if (document.GetElementById('flashlight').src == "img\flashlight.png") {
        image.src="img\flashlightON.png";

    } else (document.GetElementById('flashlight').src == "img\flashlightON.png"); {
                image.src="img\flashlight.png";
                } 
            }
```

and here is my **HTML**:

```
<button type="button" onClick="changeImage()" class="classname"> </button>
```

Comment: function changeImage() {
debugger;
    if (document.GetElementById('flashlight').src == "img\flashlight.png") {
        image.src="img\flashlightON.png";

    } else (document.GetElementById('flashlight').src == "img\flashlightON.png"); {
                image.src="img\flashlight.png";
                } 
            } // and test it

Comment: Did nothing. Just so you guys know, im a student programmer in my first year. I put an alert box to test it again, but he gave me the alert, so i guessed it is something in my cod', but I have no clue?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is case sensitive. In your case it is getElementById and not GetElementById. You placed your alert probably as the first thing in your function and therefore that part worked. Javascript is not precompiled so you just get the syntax error at the moment the line is trying to be executed.

You can use firebug to debug javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors. Use this:

```
function changeImage() {

  var image = document.getElementById('flashlight');

  if (image.src == "img/flashlight.png") {

    image.src = "img/flashlightON.png";

  } else {

    image.src = "img/flashlight.png";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive so the first mistake is in document.GetElementById. It should have been document.getElementById in order to change the src you can bind the onclick to the button in the js part itself like:

```
theButton.onclick = function pictureChange()
```

The complete working example is in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaU7L/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... You'll need to add a src to your img in html

```js
    
function swapImage() {
      if (document.getElementById("flashlight").src.endsWith("Images/Image1.png") == true)//Comparison
      {
        document.getElementById("flashlight").src = "Images/Image2.png";//assignment  
      }
      else if (document.getElementById("flashlight").src.endsWith("Images/Image2.png") == true)
      {
        document.getElementById("flashlight").src = "Images/Image1.png";
      }
    }
```